# How to get background pictures for the Music + Videos hub?

Tags: zune, music

I have seen pictures of the `music + video` hub when opened, showing background pictures of the artists/albums you have on your phone.

[image]

When I open the `music + video` hub on my device, all I get for a background is a black nothing. How do I get this app to have background pictures?

I've looked this up and found a [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/zune/forum/music-phone/zune-hub-in-wp7-wont-update-background-and-live/53c96b3c-ccbd-4a5b-a42d-e63aa2577657) that makes sense. It says that the primary hotmail account that is synced with the WP device needs to be a US account. I have already setup and synchronized an Indian account and it seems the only way to get background pictures for the `music + video` hub is:

1. Create a US account.
2. Hard reset my phone
3. Set US account as my primary.

Does anyone have a solution that will not require a reset?

Comment: Alternatively, and totally inappropriate for here, does anyone know how I can petition Microsoft to open an Indian Zune Marketplace? That seems to be a better solution to get the background pictures without a reset.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a US account, as I get them with a UK account; although not for all artists

Comment: Yeah! Any account that Zune Music Marketplace supports should do.

Comment: Add your voice to this feature suggestion:
http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3115643-make-artist-background-and-smartdj-features-availa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently its not possible without going the reset way, which is why I am tolerating the black background myself.

You can request for new features on here.
http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions

Comment: Requested!! Now to wait patiently.