# Where is the option to map a Windows Phone's location?

Tags: find-my-phone

The windows phone 'Help and how-to' guide has [steps to map a phone's location](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-in/howto/wp7/basics/find-a-lost-phone.aspx). When at step 2, after clicking **My Phone** and then clicking **Find My Phone**, all I get are three options to Ring, Lock and Erase the phone. Isn't this where the option to map the phone should be?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to check the option **Save my location every few hours for better mapping** under the **find my phone** section of the Windows Phone system settings to be able to map a Windows Phone's location.

Turns out, I'm in India and have used an Indian Windows Live account as my primary account on the phone. So the **Save my location every few hours for better mapping** checkbox will not be there in the phone, and I'll not be able to map my phone's location. Just like [this option](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/67/how-to-get-background-pictures-for-the-music-videos-hub). Pity!

Answer (score 6):

Have you enabled this in the phone settings? The steps to do that are at the bottom of the [page you linked to](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-gb/howto/wp7/basics/find-a-lost-phone.aspx) under "To change settings for Find My Phone":

In the Settings app, scroll down the list (it's *not* alphabetical), and below "apeech", you'll see "find my phone".

Click into that, and ensure that at least "Save my location every few hours for better mapping" is checked.

The documentation also states the following about the "Connect to these features more quickly" option:

> The Find My Phone service uses text messaging to send commands to your phone. Tick this option to use push notifications instead. Why? Push notifications can be faster than text messages and if your mobile operator charges you for each incoming text message, push notifications might also be cheaper. Also, My Phone can only send 15 text messages to your phone in a three-day period. With push notifications, there's no limit.

Note that on top of this, not all features are available in every region/country. See [Windows Phone Features and Service Availability](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsphone/en-gb/howto/wp7/basics/feature-and-service-availability.aspx) for more details.